# Check if all the values in range are present in the table or not, SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables which are related in a way mentioned below.

- Table 1 contains three columns `ProductId`, `VersionIn` and `VersionOut`
- Table2 contains columns `ProductId` and `Version`

I need to filter out the records of Table 1 based on the criteria below.

If Table 2 has all the versions between `VersionIn` (inclusive) and `VersionOut` (exclusive) `[VersionIn, VersionOut)` then the record is selected else it needs to be discarded. What gets discarded is of interest here.

For example: Table1

```
ProductId   VersionIn    VersionOut
-----------------------------------
   100          1            3
   100          3            6
```

Table2

```
ProductId   Version
-------------------
   100         1
   100         2
   100         3
   100         4
   101         1
```

In this scenario, record 1 of Table1 is valid, because version 1, 2 is present in Table 2. But record 2 of Table1 is invalid (and of interest) because 5 missing in the table(Since, VersionIn =3 , VersionOut=6 means [3, 6) or [3,5])

I tried this:

```
select 
    T1.ProductId, T1.VersionIdIn, T1.VersionIdOut, T2.VersionId 
from 
    Table1 as T1 
inner join 
    Table2 as T2 on T1.ProductId = T2.ProductId 
                 and T2.VersionId between T1.VersionIdIn and T2.VersionIdOut
```

and the way I am checking whether all the consecutive ones are present is by using below query:

```
select 
    T1.ProductId, T1.VersionIdIn, T1.VersionIdOut, count(VersionId) 
from
    Table1 as T1 
inner join 
    Table2 as T2 on T1.ProductId = T2.ProductId 
                 and T2.VersionId between T1.VersionIdIn and T1.VersionIdOut - 1 
group by 
    ProductId, VersionIdIn, VersionIdOut
```

If count is less than *VersionOut-VersionIn* then there are missing values in Table2.

I want to know whether this approach is correct and fool proof and better way of doing this is possible.I am new to SQL and can appreciate its power, but at times feel constrained when it comes to programming conditions which I find much easier in Programming Languages

Comment: Looks good to me. Better than doing a sum.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution would be incorrect if there are records in Table2 with duplicate values of ProductID and Version.  You could either make sure there is a unique index on those two fields, or your query could use Count(Distinct VersionID) instead of Count(VersionID).  Otherwise, I can't think of a way where this would go wrong.